# what is computation steps, implementation, and comment of program?

Tags: python

let me write simply code here. How to write the computation steps or implementation document?
is computation steps same as an in-line comment?

```
def test(letter):
   print(type(letter))
test("example")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think perhaps what you're asking about are [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

```
def test(letter):
   """
   this function outputs the type of its input parameter
   all of the information within these triple quotes, placed directly below the method or class decleration are known as a docstring

   :param letter: blah blah blah
   :return None
   """
   print(type(letter))

   # this here is a single line comment

   """
   this here is a 
   multiline comment
   """

test("example")
```

Comment: Yes, but what is computation steps?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the term 'computation steps'?

Comment: I just found out what is computational steps, it is the logic of the solution. I think it is like in-line comment but describe in word and not in programming languages

Comment: I think what you're referring to are simply comments (for single line use `#`, for multiline use `"""`, that go above lines of code.